# Complex number triangular inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

For two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, which of the following holds true?

$$|z_1|+|z_2|\geq|z_1+z_2|$$

$$|z_1|+|z_2|\geq|z_1-z_2|$$

Please explain why the other one is void, thanks.

Comment: The two are entirely equivalent, via $\,z_2 \mapsto -z_2\,$.

Comment: Um.... what can one say but that that is the triangle inequality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both valid. First line is the standard triangle inequality that is usually represented in textbooks. The second line is just the first line with some $w_2 = -z_2$. Indeed,

$|z_1+w_2| \le |z_1|+|w_2|= |z_1| + |-z_2| = |z_1| + |z_2|$

Comment: Can I find the minimum value of $|1+z|+|1-z|$ using both of them?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL First need to turn things around: $|x+y|\ge|x|-|y|$ is a consequence of $x=(-y)+(x-(-y))$, so $|x|\ge|-y|+|x+y|$. Similarly $|x+y|\ge|y|-|x|$, so you conclude $|x+y|\ge||x|-|y||$ (*reverse triangle inequality*). Now you can use *that* inequality.